# I don't get all the data from mysql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, backend

I've been searching for this for while but didn't find anything related.
So my problem is that I do get all the data from mysql with while(). However, all the articles I am trying to get displays as only 1 article even though the content is different. Sorry, it's not easy to explain that but see pictures below:

My database:

[image: My database]

How it is displayed:

[image: How it is displayed]

my articlesFunction.php code:

```
// check if user is logged in to view the content:
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && !isset($_SESSION['loggedinAdmin'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}else{

}

//
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $displayUsername = $row['username'];
    $displayArticleName = $row['name'];
    $displayArticleDescription = $row['description'];

    $fullArticle = 'Article name: '.$displayArticleName.'<br/> This article was posted by: '.$displayUsername.'<br/>'.$displayArticleDescription.'<hr/>';   
}?>
//
```

my articles.php:

```
    <?php 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                  UNFINISHED                                       //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    session_start(); 
    require_once 'connect.php';
    include 'articlesFunction.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Blog posts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/articles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bannerDiv" style="background-image: url(images/banner.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%; height:150px;">
        <h2 id="bannerTitle"><u><i>Articles about travel that everyone loves...</i></u></h2>
        <p><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></p>
        <span id="BannerMenu"><?php echo 'logged in as: '.$_SESSION['username'].' ';?></span><a href="logout.php"><button>Logout</button></a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="articles">
            <div id="Display Articles">
            <h1><u>Our set of articles:</u>
            </h1>
            <div id="display">
            <?php
                echo $fullArticle;
            ?>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I hope you understand my issue now. First, in this example, when I put it alone in the div, I only get the oldest article and I get only 1. If I add a while to the div, It gives me the results in the picture above:

So, how can I display the articles (all of them) and each one to be different as they are in the database.

Comment: You overwrite the variable on every iteration. Concatenate or make it an array. `$fullArticle = 'Article name:` <-- overwrites everytime..

Comment: replace  `$fullArticle = ` with  `$fullArticle .= `  you are constantly replacing the contents of $fullArticle

Comment: Also depending on how store that data you might be open to XSS injections.

Comment: Thanks everybody! 
This community is great :) 

the concatenating worked (.=) However now, it says: "Undefined variable: fullArticle " . If I define it as = ''; (empty). Then the error goes away but I get the old problem. 

So how to fix this? 

Sorry for my all questions but I am new in php and programming overall.

And thanks again :)

Comment: You need to define the variable first. You can't concatenate a variable that doesn't exist. So `$fullArticle = '';` before the `while`.

Comment: Oh ye... Before while... 

Thanks chris, you are great :) How do I upvote? or give reputation? There are no vote up arrows. Didn't find it nor near the comment or on profiles... 

Thanks again everybody

Comment: I think you need 20 reputation to upvote. Also these are comments, not an "answer", I can post this as answer. Also keep in mind if users are posting any content they want there is nothing stoping them from altering how your page will display.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks everybody! Appreciated

Comment: @JamalJubran please accept the answer below if that is what worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your variable on every iteration of the `while` loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $displayUsername = $row['username'];
    $displayArticleName = $row['name'];
    $displayArticleDescription = $row['description'];

    $fullArticle = 'Article name: '.$displayArticleName.'<br/> This article was posted by: '.$displayUsername.'<br/>'.$displayArticleDescription.'<hr/>';   
}
```

so as a simple example

```
$a = 0;
$b = 3;
while($a < $b){
     $output = $a;
     $a++;
}
echo $output;
```

This gives back `2` because `$output` is being over written every-time. There are two approaches to keeping all the values.

Option one, concatenate the variable

```
$a = 0;
$b = 3;
$output = '';
while($a < $b){
     $output .= $a;
     $a++;
}
echo $output;
```

Which will output `012`. We have to define the variable before using it with the `.=`. With the `.=` it is trying to concatenate the value first so it must already exist.

Option two, store the values in an array

```
$a = 0;
$b = 3;
while($a < $b){
     $output[] = $a;
     $a++;
}
print_r($output);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

This way is a bit more work because when you want to access it later you have to re-iterate through it. However it can be better if you want to be able to access each data point separately.

```
foreach($output as $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```

Also note if users are providing their usernames, article name, or description and you aren't filtering that this will open you to XSS injections.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#A_Positive_XSS_Prevention_Model

Usage in your actual code would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$fullArticle = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $displayUsername = $row['username'];
    $displayArticleName = $row['name'];
    $displayArticleDescription = $row['description'];

    $fullArticle .= 'Article name: '.$displayArticleName.'<br/> This article was posted by: '.$displayUsername.'<br/>'.$displayArticleDescription.'<hr/>';   
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code, in order to avoid the errors you mentioned in the comments;

```
//init fullname variable
$fullArticle = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $displayUsername = $row['username'];
    $displayArticleName = $row['name'];
    $displayArticleDescription = $row['description'];

    $fullArticle .= 'Article name: '.$displayArticleName.'<br/> This article was posted by: '.$displayUsername.'<br/>'.$displayArticleDescription.'<hr/>';   
}?>
//
```